# Jquery ajax() method why did not get javascript text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 pages. One is index.php and other is index2.php. I have some text in index.php which put by append() jquery method. In my index2.php there is empty but I included ck.js in index2.php where I called ajax() method to get index.php text specially which was create by append() method.

by ajax() method I have got all data from index.php without which I was wanted.

index.php code >

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <h3>this is heading</h3>
      <div class="mini">
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/my_script.js"></script>
</body>
```

my_script.js code >

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $(".mini ul").append("<li>Bangladesh</li><li>Chittangong</li>");
  });
}(jQuery));
```

result is >

this is heading

Bangladesh
Chittangong

now, index2.php code >

```html
<body>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ck.js"></script>
</body>
```

ck.js code >

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "index.php",
      beforeSend: function() {},
      success: function(html) {
        var xyz = $(html).find(".mini").html();
        console.log(xyz);
      }
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

result >
[image]

I have 2 questions, why li tag 
data not come and how can I get these ?
Thanks all and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: you are consuming  index3.php in your ajax call like `url: "index3.php",` but your original page is index.php .

Comment: also  `$(".mini ul").append("<li>Bangladesh</li><li>Chittangong</li>");` this code only works with `$(document).ready()` when loading the original page . The script is not executed when calling through ajax.You just get the original html back.

Comment: I think the problem is more that the JavaScript is NOT executed when you do a dynamic AJAX call like hat, you just get the HTML and not what the page looks like in your browser.

Comment: @MustafaMahmud check my comment above

Comment: you should check for errors in your ajax call, you would probably have seen a `404` error and corrected yourself. In case it still doesn't work with the good filename, try to set the request `dataType` to `html` or `text`

Comment: $(function(){}) is same $(document).ready()

Comment: @Niladri `$(function()` is a jQuery shortcut for `$(document).ready()` actually

Comment: @MustafaMahmud I also said about the ajax call not executing the javascript. Have you read it?

Comment: @Kaddath here is console.log screen, not there is no 404 , and also no error

Comment: Js is actually not evaluated in an ajax call. Maybe you should explain more precisely what you are trying to do with all these files, as there should be better solutions, like why not include another file with `include` instead of doing an ajax call in an ajax call? note that if you want to send JS code in PHP, you have to `echo` it and eval in client side, which is really **really** not safe

Comment: @MustafaMahmud my comment about the 404 was for the wrong filename `index3.php` but you corrected it already

Answer (score 0):

Code that you get using ajax is not interpreted automatically.
you have to append the html you recieved to your document and then make a call to a function that you've added.

A best pratice is to concatenate pages using php's `include` instruction
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

you can also get javascript file itself with ajax and then execute one of its function.

```
$.getScript("js/ck.js");
```